# Npgsql.PostgresException error on ExecuteReader when attempting to query PostgreSQL database in C# Winform

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql, executereader

I'm trying to get a list of strings from a database query and put those in a ComboBox.

The code that I'm attempting to do that with starts with the following on my from in a `DataGridVew` Cell Click event:

```
// Bind combobox to dgv and than add list of New Values to combobox
DataGridViewComboBoxCell cboNewValueList = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();

// Get fields to build New Value query
List<string> lsNewValuesResult = new List<string>();
string strCategory = dtCategories.Rows[e.RowIndex][1].ToString();
string strCompanyName = cboSelectCompany.Text;
string strQueryGetNewValuesValidationInfo = "SELECT validationdb, validationtable, validationfield, validationfield2, validationvalue2" +
                                        " FROM masterfiles.categories" +
                                        " WHERE category = @category";

// Pass validation info query to db class and return list of New Values
db getListOfNewValues = new db();
lsNewValuesResult = getListOfNewValues.GetNewValuesList(strQueryGetNewValuesValidationInfo, strCategory, strCompanyName);

//Populate the combobox with the list of New Values
foreach (string strListItem in lsNewValuesResult)
{
    cboNewValueList.Items.Add(strListItem);
}
```

I need to use the above query to find out what table and fields I need to for the query to populate `lsNewValuesResult`.

In `GetNewValuesList`I have this code:

```
public List<string> GetNewValuesList(string strValidationInfoQuery, string strCategory, string strCompanyName)
{
    List<string> lsValidationInfo = new List<string>();
    List<string> lsNewValuesList = new List<string>();

    using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString))
    using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(strValidationInfoQuery, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@cateogry", strCategory));
        conn.Open();

        using (NpgsqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int intReaderIndex;
                for (intReaderIndex = 0; intReaderIndex <= reader.FieldCount - 1; intReaderIndex++)
                {
                    // reader indexes 3 & 4 correspond to categories.validationfield2 and validationvalue2, which can be null
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader[intReaderIndex].ToString()))
                    {
                        lsValidationInfo.Add("");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lsValidationInfo.Add(reader.GetString(intReaderIndex));
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("reader index " + intReaderIndex + ": " + reader.GetString(intReaderIndex));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Use the items in lsValidationInfo to build the query to get the New Values
}
```

On the `ExecuteReader()` line, though I'm getting an Npgsql.PostgresException, "operator does not exist: @ character varying'".

What's puzzling me is that I modeled this after another block of code in the same project that does the same thing successfully. It was pretty much a copy/paste and then change the parameter and object names for the new function.

Comment: This error usually occurs when comparing different types. For example when comparing int to varchar.

Comment: @Maxqueue, That makes sense, however you can see that I pull the Category value as a string from a DGV cell: `string strCategory = dtCategories.Rows[e.RowIndex][1].ToString();` and it's passed as a string to `GetNewValuesList()`.

Comment: @Maxqueue. One of my tenets of troubleshooting is "change something and see if that changes the outcome". So I "hard-coded" the category: `" WHERE category = '" + strCategory + "'"` and it worked fine. Obviously not ideal, but for now as long as it works until I figure out what the real issue is with paramaterizing it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i think problem is with following line:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@cateogry", strCategory));
```

Try replacing with following:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("category", strCategory);
```

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say that you're right - embarrassed because that's the code that I have in the original, working function. No idea why/how I ended up with the broken one! Thanks!

Comment: Np. It happens all the time. Second pair of eyes does wonders

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to write it, with this you can also provide other attributes like Parameter direction like `OUT` and `INOUT` as well-

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@cateogry", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar){ Value = strCategory,Direction= ParameterDirection.Input });
```

Thanks!